Valores de variables de entorno duplicados
Estoy trabajando con .NET 8.0 con EF Core.
Trato de hacer una centralización de las variables de entorno puesto que tengo dos archivos de configuración. Uno es el appsettings.Development.json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=database;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"
  }
}

(Por otra parte, el DefaultConnection me gustaría desglosarlo, pero eso es otro cantar, si se resuelve también guay)
Y por otra parte tengo el docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8443:443"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=database;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;

  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: database
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:

Como se puede apreciar aquí hay DOS sitios donde se dirigen las variables de entorno, uno en el ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection y otro en el fragmento de environments de postgres.
¿Cómo podría centralizarlo todo y cambiar las variables solamente en UN solo sitio?
Muchas gracias

Pero eso son dos entornos distintos de ejecucion.. esta bien tener mas de un lugar con las variables de entorno, porque una cosa es tu ejecucion adentro de tu docker y otra tu ejecucion en tu entorno de desarrollo...

Vale perfecto, entonces no he dicho nada.
